# How can I implement asynchronous pattern for save method in C#?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am working on a project where I am implementing a SaveSettings method which saves lot of settings to a xml file.

Problem is it takes time to do that, that's why when I click Save button on my form my UI just hangs/stops for a while.

The method looks like below

```
public void SaveSettings(SettingsType settingsType)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(_settingsFile))
            {
                File.Create(_settingsFile);
            }

            var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(_settingsFile);

            switch (settingsType)
            {
                case SettingsType.Measurement:
                    SaveMeasurementSettings(ref xmlDoc);
                    break;
                case SettingsType.Display:
                    SaveDisplaySettings(ref xmlDoc);
                    break;
                case SettingsType.Common:
                    SaveCommonSettings(ref xmlDoc);
                    break;
                case SettingsType.View:
                    SaveViewSettings(ref xmlDoc);
                    break;
                case SettingsType.InputChannel:
                    SaveInputChannelSettings(ref xmlDoc);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            xmlDoc.Save(_settingsFile);
    }
```

I want to make SaveSettings method asynchronous something BeginSave/EndSave so that when I call BeginSave my UI should go smooth. I have no BackgroundWorker as I am using .Net Compact Framework.

Any guidance on implementing Asynchronous pattern please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Save()` of `XDocument` can be implemented as:

```
public void Save(string xmlFilePath)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SaveSettings));
    thread.Start(xmlFilePath);
}

private void SaveSettings(object data)
{
    string xmlFilePath;
    if ((xmlFilePath = data as string) != null)
    {
        this.SaveSettingsFile(xmlFilePath);
    }
}

private void SaveSettingsFile(string xmlFilePath)
{ 
    // Save the file contents
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the accepted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071/compact-framework-threading-messagebox-displays-over-other-controls-after-optio) post.  You could also use reflector and grab the code for the BackgroundWorker class if you wanted. [Here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2004/12/backgroundworker-sample.html) is an implementation of it to get you started.

There is also an article on MSDN about this: [Microsoft .NET Compact Framework Background Processing Techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446488.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using [.Net Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .Net 4 (or newer), consider using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx).  They're an easier way to deal with asynchronous behavior that you're spinning up.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to put together a simplistic implementation. It is untested. Also instead of using a `Thread` see if you can use a `ThreadPool` thread in the compact framework. Hope it helps.

```
public class SettingsType {}

public class Settings
{
    private Thread _worker;

    public void SaveSettings(SettingsType type)
    {
        // save logic
    }

    public void BeginSaveSettings(SettingsType type)
    {
        _worker = new Thread(() => SaveSettings(type)) {IsBackground = true};
        _worker.Start();
    }

    public bool EndSaveSettings(TimeSpan timeOut)
    {
        return _worker.Join(timeOut);
    }
}
```